# Can't solve equation numerically (Solution in terms of Root)

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value

I am trying to solve the following equation numerically.

```
NSolve[1/4 == 1/((3 + a) (a + 1)) + a^2/((3 a + 1) (a + 1)) + 
  1/((3 + a) (a + 1)) 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[-1 - 2 a (1 + a) g12^2]) + 
  a^2/((3 a + 1) (a + 1)) 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[-1 - (2 (a + 1) )/a^2 g12^2]),a]
```

Where g12 is just a constant. Mathematica gives the solution in terms of Root[...] terms like

```
a -> Root[
  1. + (10. - 4. g12^2) #1 + (65. - 8. g12^2 + 
       4. g12^4) #1^2 + (224. - 32. g12^2 - 24. g12^4) #1^3 + (510. - 
       1016. g12^2 + 60. g12^4) #1^4 + (428. - 1976. g12^2 - 
       80. g12^4) #1^5 + (510. - 1016. g12^2 + 
       60. g12^4) #1^6 + (224. - 32. g12^2 - 24. g12^4) #1^7 + (65. - 
       8. g12^2 + 4. g12^4) #1^8 + (10. - 4. g12^2) #1^9 + #1^10 &, 1]
```

And I don't know how to deal with such a term. I have tried solving the equation in Root directly or stuff like `N[Root[...]]`, but nothing works, and the term stays unchanged. How can I get an actual tangible result out of that equation?

Comment: **Where g12 is just a constant** it works for me on V 13.3.1 screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x5g2.png)  did you set g12 to the constant you had?

Comment: **I have tried solving the equation in Root directly or stuff like N[Root[...]]** that will not work if your `g12` does not have numerical value.  Try setting `g12` to numerical value first, it should work then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 1/4 == 
   1/((3 + a) (a + 1)) + a^2/((3 a + 1) (a + 1)) + 
    1/((3 + a) (a + 1)) 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[-1 - 2 a (1 + a) g12^2]) + 
    a^2/((3 a + 1) (a + 1)) 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[-1 - (2 (a + 1))/a^2 g12^2]);
```

Using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for the exact solutions

```
(sol = Solve[eqn, a]) // Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

For the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions to return a numeric value, `g12` must have a numeric  value.

For example, for `g12 == 3`

```
eqn /. sol /. g12 -> 3 // RootReduce

(* {False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False} *)
```

As indicated in the warning message, not all solutions are valid for all values of the parameter `g12`

Selecting the two valid solutions for `g12 == 3`,

```
Pick @@ ({sol, eqn /. sol} /. g12 -> 3 // RootReduce) // N

(* {{a -> -0.486416 - 0.873728 I}, {a -> -0.486416 + 0.873728 I}} *)
```

**EDIT:** For purely imaginary `g12` and real `a`

```
eqn2 = eqn /. g12 -> I*g // Simplify

(* ((a^2 (3 + Sqrt[-1 + (2 g^2)/a^2 + (2 g^2)/a]))/(1 + 3 a) + (
  3 + Sqrt[-1 + 2 a g^2 + 2 a^2 g^2])/(3 + a))/(4 (1 + a)) == 1/4 *)

(sol2 = Solve[{eqn2, {a, g} ∈ Reals}, a]) // Short
```

[image]

```
DeleteDuplicates[a /. sol2 /. ConditionalExpression[e_, cond_] :> cond]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[a /. sol2], {g, -1.1, 1.1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Im[Subscript[g, 12]], a})]
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be posible to insert an imaginary value for g12? Because from the analytical calculations I have done I expect g12 to be purely imaginary and alpha purely real.

Comment: Or more generally, would there be a way to check for which values of g12 (if any) a stays real?

Comment: I think maybe this is the question you wanted to ask? It’s certainly reasonable. But very different from what was actually asked.